# I want to run my sh file continuously even if I close my Putty connection

Tags: php, linux, command-line, putty

I have a file called `example.sh` that I want to run on my server, this file opens a TCP port connection so that my tracking unit can connect to it.

I use the following command to run the file in putty `bash ./example.sh` and that executes the file and it runs the php file perfectly.

But the problem is that when I close my **Putty** connection, then the script also dies. Now I have made a cronjob to run my `example.sh` file and that seems to work, but when I want to start the script manually, I'm stuck. Can someone tell me what linux command to use to run the file and then be able to close my Putty connection?

Answer (score 4):

`bash ./example.sh &`

`&` in the end will send the process in the background. And then you should be able to close your putty.

Comment: You may need to prefix with nohup: `nohup bash example.sh &`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [batch(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_batch.htm), perhaps as `batch -f example.sh`; and [nohup(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) could be useful too.

Then you can even logout, and your shell script will continue to run. And with `at` you can make it run at some given time.

Answer (score 0):

I would run this as a service, it is much cleaner than backgrounding the command. In /etc/init.d/ there is a skeleton file, this is a basic daemon script that you edit to fit your needs.